# Proposal distributions for covariance matrices in MCMC implementation of hierarchical models

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, covariance-matrix, hierarchical-bayesian

In a MCMC implementation of hierarchical models, with normal random effects and a Wishart prior for their covariance matrix, Gibbs sampling is typically used.

However, if we change the distribution of the random effects (e.g., to Student's-t or another one), the conjugacy is lost. In this case, what would be a suitable (i.e., easily tunable) proposal distribution for the covariance matrix of the random effects in a Metropolis-Hastings algorithm, and what should be the target acceptance rate, again 0.234?

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that if you use non-Gaussian distributions, the conjugacy of the model is lost, see:

http://www.utstat.toronto.edu/wordpress/WSFiles/technicalreports/0610.pdf

Then, you need to use other MCMC methods, such as Metropolis within Gibbs sampling or some adaptive version of it. Fortunately, there is an R package for doing so:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spBayes/index.html

**The recommended acceptance rate is 0.44** but, of course, there are some assumptions, similarly as in the case of the 0.234.

Are you [THE](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Joint-Models-Longitudinal-Time-Event/dp/1439872864) Dimitris Rizopoulos?